# Represent T* as concrete type

Tags: scala, types, projection, concrete

`(T,T)*` resolves to `Seq[(T,T)]` after erasure, but how to represent `(T,T)*` itself as a type?

The reason I ask is there's an API I'm using that defines a:

```
def foo(bar: (String,String)*) = ...
```

but fails when I try to pass in a `Seq[(String,String)]`.

My pull request to add in:

```
def foo(bar: Seq[(String,String)]) = ...
```

blows up due to the 2 methods having the same type after erasure.

Are star projections able to be represented as a concrete type?

Comment: There is no type `T*` (for any `T`). It's only relevant as a kind of pattern for passing multiple actual parameters bound to a single formal parameter with some sort of `Seq[T]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `Seq` if you follow it with `:_*` like this:

```
val s:Seq[(String, String)] = Seq( ("a", "b"), ("c", "d"), ... )
foo(s:_*)
```

So you shouldn't need both signatures.

Comment: +1 thanks! I'd prefer not use :_* at each call site, a bit cumbersome/cryptic, but better than the implicit ListMap hack I had in place to satisfy one of the API method's overloads.

Comment: I agree.  I wish there was a way to make the signature work for both cases cleanly, but I'm not aware of one.  Perhaps someone else will come along and tell us a way to make it work.

Comment: It's a little strange, but considering how confusing other forms of magic can be, such as autotupling, it would be surprising if it could work seamlessly to hide the vargs without being surprising.

Answer (score 3):

To disambiguate the erased signatures:

```
scala> class X { def f(is: Int*) = is.sum }
defined class X

scala> class Y extends X { def f(is: Seq[Int])(implicit d: DummyImplicit): Int = f(is: _*) }
defined class Y

scala> new Y().f(1 to 10)
res3: Int = 55
```

or this is better, the signatures in collections always look like this to mean "two or more":

```
scala> class X {
     | def f(i: Int): Int = i
     | def f(is: Seq[Int]): Int = is.sum
     | def f(i: Int, j: Int, rest: Int *): Int = i + j + rest.sum
     | }
defined class X

scala> new X().f(3)
res9: Int = 3

scala> new X().f(3,4)
res10: Int = 7

scala> new X().f(3,4,5)
res11: Int = 12

scala> new X().f(1 to 10)
res12: Int = 55
```

You can't refer to a repeated parameter type, just as you can't refer to a by-name parameter type as such.  So you can't convert to it.  However, you can detect it reflectively, by name:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[X].member(TermName("f")).asMethod.paramss.flatten.head.asTerm.typeSignature.typeSymbol.name
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol#NameType = <repeated>
```

There is internal API, `definitions.isRepeated(sym)`, if you want to cast for it.

Comment: +1 thorough explanation, would be nice to give both answers the nod here. Now I see why the API defined (T,T)* instead of Seq[(T,T)], repeated params.